# MongoDB MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server in Nodejs program (but mongo shell connection works)

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have a NodeJS program using mongoose 5.13.17 and I connect using this statement:

```
connect = () => mongoose.connect(url, options);

connect();
```

where `url` is `mongodb://host.docker.internal:37017/urbo-test` and `options` is

```
{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 10
}
```

However, I get an error like this:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [host.docker.internal:37017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (/workspaces/urbo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:362:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/workspaces/urbo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:570:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)]
```

As you could have figured by the URL, I'm running my program inside a docker container. My first hypothesis was some kind of network connection problem, but if I try with the mongo shell in the very same container, I can connect without problems:

```
$ mongosh mongodb://host.docker.internal:37017/urbo-test
Current Mongosh Log ID: 646b7f8ddfa2f439faf7df83
Connecting to:          mongodb://host.docker.internal:37017/urbo-test?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.9.0
Using MongoDB:          4.4.21
Using Mongosh:          1.9.0

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   2023-05-22T04:32:52.491+00:00: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
   2023-05-22T04:32:54.727+00:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
------

urbo-test>
```

As additional information, I'm getting this warning when I run my program (just before the error message):

```
(node:20834) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Any idea of what can be the reason of the problem, please? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I have modified the `options` object so now it is:

```
{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  keepAlive: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}
```

This makes deprecation warning to disappear but I'm still getting a connection error (however, the text is slightly different):

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
```

(Adding `useUnifiedTopology: true` is not enough; `reconnectTries` has to be removed or a new warning about `reconnectTries is incompatible with the unified topology is raised)

**EDIT2:** as additional information, this is my Nodejs version:

```
$ node --version
v18.16.0
```

Comment: FWIW I had a similar problem which was caused by the nodejs server and mongodb not being on the same docker network.

Comment: @radof thanks for your feeback! In your case you were able to connect to MongoDB using MongoDB shell (either `mongosh` or `mongo`)?

Comment: Yes, it worked via `mongo` shell (but from outside the container) but the server (running in its own container) could not connect to mongodb (in its own container). So making sure that server and db are on the same docker network and  hostname and port of the db is configured accordingly on the server resolved the problem.